# stagnation of a function and gradient descent

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, gradient-descent

I'm learning the simple gradient descent optimization. I feel i understood the concept but there is one sentence i don't get.

$\Delta x_i=\beta \frac{df}{dx}$ is the direction of steepest descent, $f$ is the function

Then it is stated

> **Stagnation** of $f$: the scalar product $\langle \frac{df}{dx}, \Delta x \rangle = 0$ directions correspond (i.e., the $(n-1)$-dimensional orthogonal subspace of the gradient)

I don't understand how should i interpret and imagine this stagnation?

Could someone please explain the above?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but am curious as to what the answer is. Certainly the set of all $\Delta x$, such that $\langle\nabla f, \Delta x\rangle=0$, is this $n-1$ dimensional orthogonal space that is orthogonal to the gradient. I don't see how we can use that information to begin describing Stagnation. Is there more information from the book that you could include?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, there is not much written. Its a presentation material, the slide contains 4 points: 1) direction of steepest increase of $f$, 2) direction of steepest descent, 3) Directions of stagnation of $f$ and 4) Gradient descent Algorithm: $x_{i+1}=x_{i}-\beta \text{grad} f$